# How to easily create fully "variadic" functions with C++ 98 standard?

Tags: macros, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, c++98, variadic-macros

The library 
https://github.com/c42f/tinyformat/blob/2f9335afd9941688e42d60cae5166b9f0600b2d1/tinyformat.h#L1104-L1116, uses this awesome trick to do "variadic" templates on C++ 98:

```cpp
inline void printfln(const char* fmt)
{
    format(std::cout, fmt);
    std::cout << '\n';
}

template<TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(n)>                                          \
void printfln(const char* fmt, TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n))                     \
{                                                                         \
    format(std::cout, fmt, TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS(n));                       \
    std::cout << '\n';                                                    \
}
```

I am trying to improve it by eliminating the requirement to duplicate the function **`printfln`** twice, i.e., one time for the base case **`inline void printfln(const char* fmt)`**, and a second time for the "variadic" part **`template<TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(n)> void printfln(const char* fmt, TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n))`**.

They are required to split the **`printfln`** function in two parts because the "variadic" function can only accept one parameter, i.e., **`printfln("something")`**. On this case, the **`TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)`** would have to expand to nothing, however, when doing so, it will cause the code to have a trailing comma **`,`**, leading to a invalid syntax on C++.

I could use the **`GNU GCC`** expansion trick with C macro Token-Pasting Operator **`##`** to remove the trailing comma, however, this is not portable because it only works for **`GNU GCC`**. Then, my goal is to define the macros already containing a leading comma as the next example:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

#define TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_0
#define TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_1 , class T1
#define TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_2 , class T1, class T2
#define TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_3 , class T1, class T2, class T3

#define TINYFORMAT_VARARGS_0
#define TINYFORMAT_VARARGS_1 , const T1& v1
#define TINYFORMAT_VARARGS_2 , const T1& v1, const T2& v2
#define TINYFORMAT_VARARGS_3 , const T1& v1, const T2& v2, const T3& v3

#define TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS_0
#define TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS_1 , v1
#define TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS_2 , v1, v2
#define TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS_3 , v1, v2, v3

#define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)

#define FACTORY(n) \
template<typename T0 TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(n)> \
inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
{ \
    fprintf(stderr, v0 TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS(n) ); \
}

TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    some( "Something %s.", "New" );
}
```

But, it does not work. The **`gcc`** compiler is going nuts when if finds a **`comma`** , right after the macro definition: **`g++ -o main -g -ggdb test_debugger.cpp --std=c++98 && ./main`**

```
test_debugger.cpp:21:19: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘T0’
 template<typename T0 TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(n)> \
                   ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:38: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                      ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:21:22: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES’
 template<typename T0 TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(n)> \
                      ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:38: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                      ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:22:24: error: ‘T0’ does not name a type
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
                        ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:38: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                      ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:22:31: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘TINYFORMAT_VARARGS’
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
                               ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:38: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                      ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:22:52: error: default template arguments may not be used in function templates without -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
                                                    ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:38: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                      ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp: In function ‘void some(const int&)’:
test_debugger.cpp:24:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS’
     fprintf(stderr, v0 TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS(n) ); \
                        ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:38: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                      ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp: At global scope:
test_debugger.cpp:21:19: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘T0’
 template<typename T0 TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(n)> \
                   ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:43: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                           ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:21:22: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES’
 template<typename T0 TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(n)> \
                      ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:43: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                           ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:22:24: error: ‘T0’ does not name a type
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
                        ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:43: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                           ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:22:31: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘TINYFORMAT_VARARGS’
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
                               ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:43: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                           ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:22:52: error: default template arguments may not be used in function templates without -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
                                                    ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:43: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                           ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:22:13: error: redefinition of ‘template<<declaration error> > void some(const int&)’
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
             ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:43: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                           ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:22:13: note: ‘template<<declaration error> > void some(const int&)’ previously declared here
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
             ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:38: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                      ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:21:19: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘T0’
 template<typename T0 TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(n)> \
                   ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:48: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                                ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:21:22: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES’
 template<typename T0 TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(n)> \
                      ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:48: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                                ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:22:24: error: ‘T0’ does not name a type
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
                        ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:48: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                                ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:22:31: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘TINYFORMAT_VARARGS’
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
                               ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:48: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                                ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:22:52: error: default template arguments may not be used in function templates without -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
                                                    ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:48: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                                ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:22:13: error: redefinition of ‘template<<declaration error> > void some(const int&)’
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
             ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:48: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                                ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:22:13: note: ‘template<<declaration error> > void some(const int&)’ previously declared here
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
             ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:38: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                      ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:21:19: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘T0’
 template<typename T0 TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(n)> \
                   ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:53: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                                     ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:21:22: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES’
 template<typename T0 TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(n)> \
                      ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:53: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                                     ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:22:24: error: ‘T0’ does not name a type
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
                        ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:53: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                                     ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:22:31: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘TINYFORMAT_VARARGS’
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
                               ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:53: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                                     ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:22:52: error: default template arguments may not be used in function templates without -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
                                                    ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:53: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                                     ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:22:13: error: redefinition of ‘template<<declaration error> > void some(const int&)’
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
             ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:53: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                                     ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:22:13: note: ‘template<<declaration error> > void some(const int&)’ previously declared here
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
             ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:38: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                      ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
test_debugger.cpp:31:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘some(const char [14], const char [4])’
     some( "Something %s.", "New" );
                                  ^
test_debugger.cpp:22:13: note: candidate: template<<declaration error> > void some(const int&)
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
             ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:38: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                      ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:22:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
 inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n)) \
             ^
test_debugger.cpp:18:38: note: in expansion of macro ‘FACTORY’
 #define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)
                                      ^
test_debugger.cpp:27:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM’
 TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_debugger.cpp:31:34: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
     some( "Something %s.", "New" );
                                  ^
```

In my understanding my **`TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) m(0) m(1) m(2) m(3)`** macro should create the following 4 valid C++ "variadic" functions:

```cpp
template<typename T0> 
inline void some(const T0& v0) 
{ 
    fprintf(stderr, v0 ); 
}

template<typename T0, class T1> 
inline void some(const T0& v0, const T1& v1) 
{ 
    fprintf(stderr, v0, v1 ); 
}

template<typename T0, class T1, class T2> 
inline void some(const T0& v0, const T1& v1, const T1& v2) 
{ 
    fprintf(stderr, v0, v1, v2); 
}

template<typename T0, class T1, class T2, class T3> 
inline void some(const T0& v0, const T1& v1, const T1& v2, const T1& v3) 
{ 
    fprintf(stderr, v0, v1, v2, v3); 
}
```

Why the **`gcc`** preprocessor is not generating correctly my 4 "variadic" template functions as above?

For reference, I am using:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

## Update

Output of **`g++ -o main -E -g -ggdb test_debugger.cpp --std=c++98`**

```
# 797 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
}
# 2 "test_debugger.cpp" 2
# 27 "test_debugger.cpp"

# 27 "test_debugger.cpp"
template<typename T0 TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(0)> 
inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(0)) { fprintf(
# 27 "test_debugger.cpp" 3 4
((__getreent())->_stderr)
# 27 "test_debugger.cpp"
, v0 TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS(0) ); } template<typename T0 TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(1)> 
inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(1)) { fprintf(
# 27 "test_debugger.cpp" 3 4
((__getreent())->_stderr)
# 27 "test_debugger.cpp"
, v0 TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS(1) ); } template<typename T0 TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(2)> 
inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(2)) { fprintf(
# 27 "test_debugger.cpp" 3 4
((__getreent())->_stderr)
# 27 "test_debugger.cpp"
, v0 TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS(2) ); } template<typename T0 TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(3)> 
inline void some(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(3)) { fprintf(
# 27 "test_debugger.cpp" 3 4
((__getreent())->_stderr)
# 27 "test_debugger.cpp"
, v0 TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS(3) ); }

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    some( "Something %s.", "New" );
}
```

## Update 2

I tried to change the order of the definition in hope the C preprocessor would expand things right, but it just expanded exactly as before:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_0
#define TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_1 , class T1
#define TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_2 , class T1, class T2
#define TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_3 , class T1, class T2, class T3

#define TINYFORMAT_VARARGS_0
#define TINYFORMAT_VARARGS_1 , const T1& v1
#define TINYFORMAT_VARARGS_2 , const T1& v1, const T2& v2
#define TINYFORMAT_VARARGS_3 , const T1& v1, const T2& v2, const T3& v3

#define TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS_0
#define TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS_1 , v1
#define TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS_2 , v1, v2
#define TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS_3 , v1, v2, v3

#define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m) \
    m(TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(0),TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(0),TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS(0)) \
    m(TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(1),TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(1),TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS(1)) \
    m(TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(2),TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(2),TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS(2)) \
    m(TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(3),TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(3),TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS(3))

#define FACTORY(argtypes,varargs,passargs) \
template<typename T0 argtypes> \
inline void some(const T0& v0 varargs) \
{ \
    fprintf(stderr, v0 passargs); \
}
TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY)

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    some( "Something %s.", "New" );
}
```

## Update 3

As [@aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459640) commented, I was missing the definition of **`TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_ ## n`**, this is a fixed version:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

#define TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_0(...)
#define TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_1(...) __VA_ARGS__ class T1
#define TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_2(...) __VA_ARGS__ class T1, class T2
#define TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_3(...) __VA_ARGS__ class T1, class T2, class T3

#define TINYFORMAT_VARARGS_0(...)
#define TINYFORMAT_VARARGS_1(...) __VA_ARGS__ const T1& v1
#define TINYFORMAT_VARARGS_2(...) __VA_ARGS__ const T1& v1, const T2& v2
#define TINYFORMAT_VARARGS_3(...) __VA_ARGS__ const T1& v1, const T2& v2, const T3& v3

#define TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS_0(...)
#define TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS_1(...) __VA_ARGS__ v1
#define TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS_2(...) __VA_ARGS__ v1, v2
#define TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS_3(...) __VA_ARGS__ v1, v2, v3

#define TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(n,...) TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_ ## n (__VA_ARGS__)
#define TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n,...)  TINYFORMAT_VARARGS_  ## n (__VA_ARGS__)
#define TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS(n,...) TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS_ ## n (__VA_ARGS__)

#define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m,...) \
        m(0) m(1,__VA_ARGS__) m(2,__VA_ARGS__) m(3,__VA_ARGS__)

#define FACTORY(n,...) \
template<TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(n,__VA_ARGS__)> \
inline void some(TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n,__VA_ARGS__)) \
{ \
    fprintf(stderr, "variadic" TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS(n,,) ); \
}
TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY,)

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    some();
}
```

Expanding to: **`g++ -o main -E -g -ggdb test_debugger.cpp --std=c++98`**

```
# 797 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
}
# 2 "test_debugger.cpp" 2
# 31 "test_debugger.cpp"

# 31 "test_debugger.cpp"
template<> 
inline void some() { fprintf(
# 31 "test_debugger.cpp" 3 4
((__getreent())->_stderr)
# 31 "test_debugger.cpp"
, "variadic" ); } template< class T1> 
inline void some( const T1& v1) { fprintf(
# 31 "test_debugger.cpp" 3 4
((__getreent())->_stderr)
# 31 "test_debugger.cpp"
, "variadic" , v1 ); } template< class T1, class T2> 
inline void some( const T1& v1, const T2& v2) { fprintf(
# 31 "test_debugger.cpp" 3 4
((__getreent())->_stderr)
# 31 "test_debugger.cpp"
, "variadic" , v1, v2 ); } template< class T1, class T2, class T3> 
inline void some( const T1& v1, const T2& v2, const T3& v3) { fprintf(
# 31 "test_debugger.cpp" 3 4
((__getreent())->_stderr)
# 31 "test_debugger.cpp"
, "variadic" , v1, v2, v3 ); }

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    some();
}
```

Now the problem is when the macro template expands to something without any template parameters, i.e., **`template<> inline void some()`**, it generates the following code:

```cpp
template<>
inline void some()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "variadic");
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    some();
}
```

Which causes C++ to compiler to throw this error:

```
test_debugger.cpp: error: ‘some’ is not a template function
 inline void some()
                  ^
test_debugger.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
test_debugger.cpp: error: ‘some’ was not declared in this scope
     some();
     ^~~~
```

Comment: Use a "`g++ -E` ..." command to see the output of the preprocessor which is the input to the compiler step. But it looks like `TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES` is never defined, so the comma you expect isn't actually seen.

Comment: @aschepler, I ran the command the they does not seem to expand. I updated the question with the output.

Comment: Well, I don't see any definition of `TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES`. You seem to be missing something like `#define TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(n) TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_ ## n`

Comment: @aschepler, You are right, I already fixed this, and now I am dealing with the edge case when the template is declared without template types, i.e., **`template<> inline void some()`**. Then, the compiler says: **`error: ‘some’ is not a template function`**. I update the question with this new problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A template can't have zero template parameters. The syntax that starts with `template <>` instead is used for an explicit specialization: a declaration to be used instead of the template for a specific set of template arguments.

So your zero-argument version will need to skip the `template <>` part. You might do something like:

```
#define TINYFORMAT_TEMPLATE_HEAD_0(...)
#define TINYFORMAT_TEMPLATE_HEAD_1(...) template < TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_1(__VA_ARGS__) >
#define TINYFORMAT_TEMPLATE_HEAD_2(...) template < TINYFORAMT_ARGTYPES_2(__VA_ARGS__) >
#define TINYFORMAT_TEMPLATE_HEAD_3(...) template < TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_3(__VA_ARGS__) >

#define TINYFORMAT_TEMPLATE_HEAD(n, ...) TINYFORMAT_TEMPLATE_HEAD_ ## n (__VA_ARGS__)

#define FACTORY(n,...) \
TINYFORMAT_TEMPLATE_HEAD(n,__VA_ARGS__) \
inline void some(TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n,__VA_ARGS__)) \
{ \
    fprintf(stderr, "variadic" TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS(n,,) ); \
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459640) help, I also managed to build this more general solution/example:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

#define TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_0(...)
#define TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_1(begin,end,...) begin __VA_ARGS__ class T1 end
#define TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_2(begin,end,...) begin __VA_ARGS__ class T1, class T2 end
#define TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_3(begin,end,...) begin __VA_ARGS__ class T1, class T2, class T3 end

#define TINYFORMAT_VARARGS_0(...)
#define TINYFORMAT_VARARGS_1(...) __VA_ARGS__ const T1& v1
#define TINYFORMAT_VARARGS_2(...) __VA_ARGS__ const T1& v1, const T2& v2
#define TINYFORMAT_VARARGS_3(...) __VA_ARGS__ const T1& v1, const T2& v2, const T3& v3

#define TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS_0(...)
#define TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS_1(...) __VA_ARGS__ v1
#define TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS_2(...) __VA_ARGS__ v1, v2
#define TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS_3(...) __VA_ARGS__ v1, v2, v3

#define TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(n,begin,end,...) TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES_ ## n (begin,end,__VA_ARGS__)
#define TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n,...)  TINYFORMAT_VARARGS_  ## n (__VA_ARGS__)
#define TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS(n,...) TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS_ ## n (__VA_ARGS__)

#define TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(m,...) \
        m(0) m(1,__VA_ARGS__) m(2,__VA_ARGS__) m(3,__VA_ARGS__)

#define FACTORY_FULLY_OPTIONAL(n,...) \
TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(n,template<,>,__VA_ARGS__) \
inline void some_optional(TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n,__VA_ARGS__)) \
{ \
    fprintf( stderr, "some_optional\n" TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS(n,,) ); \
}

#define FACTORY_WITH_EXISTENT_ARGS(n,...) \
template<class T0 TINYFORMAT_ARGTYPES(n,,,__VA_ARGS__)> \
inline void some_existent(const T0& v0 TINYFORMAT_VARARGS(n,__VA_ARGS__)) \
{ \
    fprintf( stderr, "some_existent %s\n", v0 TINYFORMAT_PASSARGS(n,__VA_ARGS__) ); \
}

TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY_FULLY_OPTIONAL,)
TINYFORMAT_FOREACH_ARGNUM(FACTORY_WITH_EXISTENT_ARGS,,)

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    some_optional();
    some_existent( "varing" );
}
```

This is the generated code: **`g++ -o main -E -g -ggdb test_debugger.cpp --std=c++98`**

```cpp
# 797 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
}
# 2 "test_debugger.cpp" 2
# 38 "test_debugger.cpp"

# 38 "test_debugger.cpp"
inline void some_optional() { fprintf(
# 38 "test_debugger.cpp" 3 4
((__getreent())->_stderr)
# 38 "test_debugger.cpp"
, "some_optional\n" ); } template< class T1 > 
inline void some_optional( const T1& v1) { fprintf(
# 38 "test_debugger.cpp" 3 4
((__getreent())->_stderr)
# 38 "test_debugger.cpp"
, "some_optional\n" , v1 ); } template< class T1, class T2 > 
inline void some_optional( const T1& v1, const T2& v2) { fprintf(
# 38 "test_debugger.cpp" 3 4
((__getreent())->_stderr)
# 38 "test_debugger.cpp"
, "some_optional\n" , v1, v2 ); } template< class T1, class T2, class T3 > 
inline void some_optional( const T1& v1, const T2& v2, const T3& v3) { fprintf(
# 38 "test_debugger.cpp" 3 4
((__getreent())->_stderr)
# 38 "test_debugger.cpp"
, "some_optional\n" , v1, v2, v3 ); }

template<class T0 > 
inline void some_existent(const T0& v0 ) { fprintf(
# 39 "test_debugger.cpp" 3 4
((__getreent())->_stderr)
# 39 "test_debugger.cpp"
, "some_existent %s\n", v0 ); } template<class T0 , class T1 > 
inline void some_existent(const T0& v0 , const T1& v1) { fprintf(
# 39 "test_debugger.cpp" 3 4
((__getreent())->_stderr)
# 39 "test_debugger.cpp"
, "some_existent %s\n", v0 , v1 ); } template<class T0 , class T1, class T2 > 
inline void some_existent(const T0& v0 , const T1& v1, const T2& v2) { fprintf(
# 39 "test_debugger.cpp" 3 4
((__getreent())->_stderr)
# 39 "test_debugger.cpp"
, "some_existent %s\n", v0 , v1, v2 ); } template<class T0 , class T1, class T2, class T3 > 
inline void some_existent(const T0& v0 , const T1& v1, const T2& v2, const T3& v3) { fprintf(
# 39 "test_debugger.cpp" 3 4
((__getreent())->_stderr)
# 39 "test_debugger.cpp"
, "some_existent %s\n", v0 , v1, v2, v3 ); }

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    some_optional();
    some_existent("varing");
}
```

Running it: **`./main`**

```
some_optional
some_existent varing
```

Related questions:

1. [comma (,) in C Macro Definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635796/comma-in-c-macro-definition)
2. [Comma in C/C++ macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842468/comma-in-c-c-macro)
3. [Using comma as macro name in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39775329/using-comma-as-macro-name-in-c-or-c)
4. [C preprocessor macro doesn't parse comma separated tokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57123398/c-preprocessor-macro-doesnt-parse-comma-separated-tokens)
5. [C-preprocessor: iteratively expand macro to comma-separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235603/c-preprocessor-iteratively-expand-macro-to-comma-separated-list)
6. [What are the valid characters for macro names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369495/what-are-the-valid-characters-for-macro-names)
7. [Concatenation of tokens in variadic macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458402/concatenation-of-tokens-in-variadic-macros)
8. [Is it possible to iterate over arguments in variadic macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872220/is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-variadic-macros)
9. [C++ preprocesor macro for accumulating comma-separated strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095550/c-preprocesor-macro-for-accumulating-comma-separated-strings)
10. [Variadic macros with zero arguments, and commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563184/variadic-macros-with-zero-arguments-and-commas)
11. [C Preprocessor Remove Trailing Comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291976/c-preprocessor-remove-trailing-comma)
12. [Is it possible to stringify a C macro that contains a comma?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551191/is-it-possible-to-stringify-a-c-macro-that-contains-a-comma)
13. [How to expand macro and delete comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747785/how-to-expand-macro-and-delete-comma)
14. [What type of content is allowed to be used as arguments for C preprocessor macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844577/what-type-of-content-is-allowed-to-be-used-as-arguments-for-c-preprocessor-macro)
15. [How does expansion of the macro parameters work in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57476237/how-does-expansion-of-the-macro-parameters-work-in-c)
16. [How to make a preprocessor macro greedy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506981/how-to-make-a-preprocessor-macro-greedy)
17. [Passing a template which requires a comma to a single-argument macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460599/passing-a-template-which-requires-a-comma-to-a-single-argument-macro)
18. [Comma in C/C++ macro passed to another macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005189/comma-in-c-c-macro-passed-to-another-macro)
19. [How to stringify a string which contains a comma?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20384709/how-to-stringify-a-string-which-contains-a-comma)